# UDA opCall __traits

Tags: attributes, d, ctfe

This code fails at the second unittest at the getA!B() call. The error is: "need 'this' for 'value' of type 'string'"

The question is. How do I get getA to always return a A, whether the UDA is a type or an opCall?

```
    static A opCall(T...)(T args) {
        A ret;
        ret.value = args[0];
        return ret;
    }

    string value;
}

@A struct B {
}

@A("hello") struct C {
}

A getA(T)() {
    foreach(it; __traits(getAttributes, T)) {
        if(is(typeof(it) == A)) {
            A ret;
            ret.value = it.value;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    assert(false);
}

unittest {
    A a = getA!C();
    assert(a.value == "hello");
}

unittest {
    A a = getA!B();
    assert(a.value == "");
}
```

Comment: in the `getA` function, change that `if` to `static if` and see what happens, that might just help

Comment: static if works like a charm. I stared at that so long that static never came to mind. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, [traits](http://dlang.org/traits.html) are evaluated at compile-time. So any introspection on values obtained via __traits must be done statically. Luckily D has the "[static if condition](http://dlang.org/version.html#staticif)" for this.

If you change

```
if(is(typeof(it) == A)) {
```

to

```
static if (is(typeof(it) == A)) {
```

you should not have problems compiling the code as `is(typeof(it) == A` can be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: What bugs me is that the foreach is not static but actually is.

Comment: Good point. There have been suggestions on the D newsgroups to have `static foreach`. In this case, foreach iterates over tuples known at compile-time, so D does not complain. :)

Comment: I followed that thread a bit. It is always funny and scary what the D frontend accepts and what not ;-)